# hibernate mapping verify if an object is mapped

Tags: hibernate

How can I check if an object is mapped or not?

I get an error cause I have an object not mapped in Hibernate

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not mapped [select prod from com.neila.Product product
```

, I wanna test before executing the code if that object is already mapped.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a mapped object". Include the full exception stack trace and the relevant code.

Comment: Code and error please..

Comment: why don't you just write an unit test to fetch dummy object?

Comment: I added the error in my question

Comment: are you running hibernate on update mode?

Comment: this error happens cause I don't have the model Product mapped via an hbm file or an annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

Suppose I have an Entity named **Test.java**.

This is not mapped in Hibernate & I try to save an instance of the class.

```
Test test = new Test();
if (configuration.getClassMapping(Test.class.getName()) != null) {
       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
       session.saveOrUpdate(test);
       tx.commit();
       session.close();
}
```

Here `configuration` & `sessionFactory` represent instances of `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` & `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` respectively.

If you remove the if condition & directly try to save the instance of Test class, you'll get exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have `com.neila.Product` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` in either Mapping Resource (If you use XML mapping) or Mapping Class (If you are using Annotations) form.

Comment: is not my problem if Product is mapped or not,
just I wanna test before executing an hql query , it should be executed only if the object is mapped 
I found somrthing like that:
ClassMetadata tClassMetadata = getSession().getClassMetadata(myObject.getClass());

    if(tClassMetadata.getIdentifier(myObject)!= null) {-- myQuery}

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one,

```
boolean isMapped = getSession().getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(
        "package.myClass") != null;

    if (!isMapped ) {
      -- my query
    }
```